# Laravel Sail will not build with ubuntu:20.04

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail

as you can see below docker is fetching an image from the ubuntu domain but without the "/" and there is 500 errors, im unsure as to why.
Can anyone give me a solution or explanation as to why this is happening?

[image: clip of error]

Comment: It looks like `apt-get update` fails, might be due to internet connection problems / server was temporary down?

Comment: I discovered that it was the new OS update for my mac, you need to change firewall settings and restart machine

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it was the new OS update for my mac, you need to change firewall settings and restart machine